# aot-compilation breaks NumberPipe

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying out ionic at the moment and came across some odd behavior.

When I start my app using `ionic serve` everything works flawlessly.
Once I have bundled the app using `ionic build browser` it crashes as soon as `NumberPipe` is invoked:

```
<span>{{sizeVertical | number:'.2-2'}}</span>
```

makes it crash with:

```
main.js:3646 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at new NumberFormat (native)
    at Function.t.format (file:///.../build/main.js:9:9621)
    at Te (file:///.../build/main.js:1:22885)
    at t.transform (file:///.../build/main.js:9:12974)
    at file:///.../www/build/main.js:1:9214
    at e.detectChangesInternal (file:///.../build/main.js:33:31019)
    (...)
```

Without the pipe everything's fine.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with AoT-compilation which I'm totally unfamiliar with.

How can I work around this? Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your pipe is correct ?  number:'.2-2'

Comment: yes, it's `<minDigitsBeforeDecimal>.<minDigitsAfterDecimal>-<maxDigitsAfterDecimal>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "discovered" that projects created with `ionic@2.0.0-rc1` still use angular@2.0.0.
As indicated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11896) updating to 2.0.1 fixed the issue.